# Which argument of MoleculeValue returns the SAS?

Tags: chemistry

*UPDATE*

The question was asked when version 12.0 was the current version. But version 12.1 of Mathematica includes the synthetic accessibility score!

```
MoleculeValue[mol, "SyntheticAccessibilityScore"]
```

A big thank you to @Jason B. for such prompt work.

---

I have been trying to calculate the synthetic accessibility score of a molecule. But I don't know which property from the extensive list returned by `MoleculeValue["Properties"]` corresponds to the SAS value.

I know that there is a function in `rdkit` called `sascorer` which computes the SAS of a molecule. And if, as [this announcement by Jason](https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/message/36188280/) suggests, the chemistry-related computations are backed by `rdkit`, I imagine that one of the `MoleculeValue`s is what I am looking for. So, my questions are:

1. Which argument (or parameter) of `MoleculeValue` returns the synthetic accessibility score of a molecule?
2. Are all (or most) of the chemical properties available through `rdkit` available in `Mathematica` by now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MoleculeValue["Properties"]` lists the available molecule properties, grouped by property type, in an association. `MoleculeValue["AllProperties"]` gives a flat list of the availaple properties.

The [synthetic accessibility score](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/master/Contrib/SA_Score/sascorer.py) is not available right now. The best way to request new molecule properties or new features for chemistry in *Mathematica* is to use the `Help->Give Feedback`.

This property in particular looks very interesting, I will look at the [original publication](http://www.jcheminf.com/content/1/1/8) and make the SAS available in a future version of the Wolfram Language.

Comment: And when I direct you to the help menu, I really do want user feedback in order to help prioritize the features we want to add.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As per your instruction, I have submitted my request for the inclusion of SAS through `Help -> Give Feedback`.

Comment: Is the existing API into rdkit user-extensible if we muck around in the paclet? Waiting for a new Mathematica version for something you need now is usually not workable

Comment: @b3m2a1, while we certainly use the rdkit for some functionality by no means do we include a full installation of it in the layout.